# Find the minimum value of $x$ such that $ax+b (\text{mod} M)$ lies in the range $[0, M-a)$, given that $M<2*a$ and $\text{gcd}(a,M) = 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here a, b, and M are constant integers and x is a variable greater than or equal to 0, that can take integer values.
I have found that the answer is $b \text{ mod}(M-a)$, but don't know how to arrive at the solution. Also, can someone intuitively explain, how the answer comes out to be so simple?

Comment: Using math formatting would improve readability - I've edited it

Comment: Make your question more clear. What is $a,b,x$, what is $M$?

Comment: @LegNaiB Thanks, I have added meaning to the variable names.